# Int variable's value won't change after being moved

Tags: vector, move-semantics

I've read the basics of move semantics and I did a couple of tests.
Case #1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    string st = "hello";
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back(st);
    cout << st;

    cin.get();
}
```

In this case, the program will not print anything because "hello" has been moved to vector[0].

Case #2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int  main()
{
    int num=5;
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(num);
    cout << num;

    cin.get();
}
```

Why does the program print "5"? I thought num would be 0 or something undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Case #1 should print "hello". If not then your compiler has bug and you should upgrade to a newer version or complain to who ever wrote it.

Case #2 correctly prints "5".

However, if you changed line 10 in case 2 from:

```
vec.push_back(st);
```

to:

```
vec.push_back(std::move(st));
```

you will get what you expected, a print to console of "" because vector "stole" the value in st.

`int` is a [fundamental type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) in c++ and trying to "steal" from an int variable doesn't realy work since it does't own any resource.

[std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a resource owner. It "owns" a char array (this isn't always true, but for simplicity we will pretend it is).

So when we pass `std::move(st)` to [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) we are calling the [T&&](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) overload of push_back which does the "stealing" by calling the [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of std::string which releases st's handle and gives it to the newly created std::string inside vec.

But if we called push_back like this: `vec.push_back(st);` this will not "steal" any thing. Instead, it will call the [const T&](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) overload of push_back which just does a simple copy by calling the normal copy constructor of `std::string` such that we will have st set to "hello" and vec[0] set with its own version of "hello".

Try this code below to see how all this works out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo() // default constructor
    {
        cout << "Foo()" << endl;
    }
    Foo(const Foo&) // copy constructor
    {
        cout << "Foo(const Foo&)" << endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo&&) // move constructor
    {
        cout << "Foo(Foo&&)" << endl;
    }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) // copy assignment operator
    {
        cout << "operator=(const Foo&)" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) // move assignment operator
    {
        cout << "operator=(Foo&&)" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        cout << "~Foo()" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Foo f; // print: Foo();

    vector<Foo> vec;
    vec.push_back(f); // print: Foo(const Foo&)
    vec.push_back(std::move(f)); // print: Foo(Foo&&)

    Foo f2; // print: Foo()
    f2 = f; // print: operator=(const Foo&)
    f2 = std::move(f); // print: operator=(Foo&&)

    cin.get();
}
```